# I'm trying to seed 2 tables with information from the same API. I filled the first table, but the 2nd one is giving me errors despite similar code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, api

The JSON data looks like this...

```
 {
    "data": [
            "scores": {
                "localteam_score": 3,
                "visitorteam_score": 1,
                      }
            "localTeam": {
                "data": {
                     "name": "Atlanta United",
                      "logo_path": "https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/teams/3/323.png",
                }
            },
            "visitorTeam": {
                "data": {
                    "name": "Sporting KC",
                    "logo_path": "https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/teams/3/323.png",
                }
            },
            "lineup": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "team_id": 3645,
                        "fixture_id": 18449920,
                        "player_id": 393,
                        "player_name": "Brad Guzan",
                        "number": 1,
                        "position": "G",}
```

For the table where I keep basic match information, I seeded it with this...

```
    require 'rest-client'
rest_client = RestClient.get 'https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/between/2022-01-01/2022-12-01/3645?api_token=__&include=localTeam,visitorTeam,goals,'
@match = JSON.parse(rest_client)


@match['data'].each do |match|
    Match.create(
        local_team: match["localTeam"]["data"]["name"],
        away_team: match["visitorTeam"]["data"]["name"],
        localteam_score: match["scores"]["localteam_score"],
        awayteam_score: match["scores"]["visitorteam_score"],
        awaylogo: match["visitorTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"],
        locallogo: match["localTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"])
    end
```

Which worked just fine and did what I wanted it to do. I needed to fill my other table, consisting of lineup data, which has been returning me "undefined method [] for nil:Nilclass" and "TypeError: no implicit conversion of string into integer" errors. So, to test, I deleted the 2nd method and kept the first, and now the first one will not even work anymore and is giving me "NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass" despite being the exact same code that was working before.

I have gone into postresql and confirmed that both tables exist and that the first one has been filled properly, but now, it's like both of those methods are busted.

Full seeds file

```
require 'json'
require 'dotenv'
require 'rest-client'
require 'open-uri'
Dotenv.load

require 'rest-client'
rest_client = RestClient.get 'https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/between/2022-01-01/2022-12-01/3645?api_token=p5o0nolOT4JUo5lYXrBFY8Ess6vuRZJ9Rt5jmOx3DmJjgZpT9ghmfYbZHIdj&include=localTeam,visitorTeam,goals,'
@match = JSON.parse(rest_client)


@match['data'].each do |match|
    Match.create(
        local_team: match["localTeam"]["data"]["name"],
        away_team: match["visitorTeam"]["data"]["name"],
        localteam_score: match["scores"]["localteam_score"],
        awayteam_score: match["scores"]["visitorteam_score"],
        awaylogo: match["visitorTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"],
        locallogo: match["localTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"])
    end 
    
@match['data'].each do |lineup|
    Lineup.create(
        display_name: lineup["lineup"]["data"]["player_name"],
        number: lineup["lineup"]["data"]["number"],
        position: lineup["lineup"]["data"]["position"],
        )
    end
```

Full error message

```
$ rails db:seed
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/db/seeds.rb:20:in `block in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/db/seeds.rb:19:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/db/seeds.rb:19:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/db/seeds.rb:20:in `block in <main>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/db/seeds.rb:19:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/db/seeds.rb:19:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/home/ubuntu/environment/rated_app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

here `"lineup": { "data": [ { "team_id": 3645, "fixture_id": 18449920, "player_id": 393, "player_name": "Brad Guzan", "number": 1, "position": "G",}`
is a hash which contains array in a key "data". Kindly run a loop with data and populate Lineup table. Like

```
@match['data'].each do |lineup|
    lineup['data'].each do |l|
       Lineup.create(
        display_name: l["player_name"],
        number: l["number"],
        position: l["position"],
        )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Lineup.create has an extra comma at the end of this line:

```
position: lineup["data"]["position"],
```

Comment: Fixed that, thanks! Still getting that same `NoMethodError: undefined method 'fetch_value' for nil:NilClass` error, however.

Answer (score -1):

> Where am I going wrong?

You are not reading the error message carefully, you're not using debugging tools, you haven't shared the **full** error message here on StackOverflow, and you're not sharing a reproducible code sample to StackOverlow (you've only shared partial/incomplete JSON data, and I have no idea where this `fetch_value` method is being defined/invoked).

The first error:

```
undefined method [] for nil:Nilclass
```

Indicates that *something* is `nil`. What is `nil`? I don't know, because you didn't share the details. Read the line number of the error message, and it will tell you which variable is `nil`.

For example, **maybe** (??) the error is coming from: `match["time"]["starting_at"]["date"]`, because `match["time"]["starting_at"]` is `nil`? Maybe the fix is to replace `"starting_at"` with `"startingAt"`?! Or maybe this field can sometimes be missing, so your code needs to handle that gracefully - e.g. `match.dig("time", "starting_at", "date")`?

Or, maybe `@lineup` is actually giving you a completely different set of data like `{ "error": { "message": "Unauthenticated", "code": 403 } }`, and so the solution is to gracefully handle invalid response statuses?

Without more information, I can only *speculate* on the possible cause and solution.

You can also use a debugging tool like [`byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) to help diagnose variables, instead of rely on re-running the code and/or using `puts` statements to see what's going on.

Comment: The JSON itself has 4,000 lines of code with a lot of information that I'm not using, so I tried to just boil it down to the bits I'm using, but I can paste it all in there, I was just trying to make it easier to view without having to scroll through it to find what I was referencing. I added in the full error messages and what my seeds looks like. And the `match["time"]["starting_at"]["date"]` never gave me an error (and worked to fill my table with the correct data) before I added the lineup section.

Comment: @FO2495 Don't be silly, I'm clearly not asking for a 4000 line JSON file. I'm asking for a [mcve]. You could easily cut the JSON down to ~40 lines and still have it fully demonstrate the nature of your problem. You neglected to include critical information from your question, like wherever `fetch_value` is mentioned in the code, and are asking us to help identify a solution... Well, a helpful starting point is to explain the problem fully, and not omit vital information for anyone to understand it.

Comment: Now looking at the updated question, I see the error is on **LINE 20** of `db/seeds.rb`. What is that? Is this even the file you've shown above, or something completely different? You could also try re-running the command with `--trace`, as the error message suggests.

Comment: I'm not being "silly", I'm just trying to learn. I'm a month into this. Have you ever been new to something before? I'll take all of the help and direction I can get, but I'm not being intentionally neglectful or "silly", I'm just genuinely trying to find help after searching around on my own for hours this morning. I thought that was what forums were useful for and I've mostly found patient and helpful people up until this moment.

Comment: @FO2495 My complaint was that you failed to include information in the question which - in my opinion - is very obviously crucial to anyone trying to understand it. Put yourself in our shoes: Just knowing that the errors are `"undefined method [] for nil:Nilclass"` and `"NoMethodError: undefined method 'fetch_value' for nil:NilClass"` (no line numbers, no valid input file, no mention of `fetch_value` anywhere in the code), can you appreciate why I felt it's a little neglectful?

Comment: Like I said, the most important thing you should be aiming to learn here is how to debug code: You'll never google a generic error message like `undefined method [] for nil:Nilclass` and find an answer to your specific problem; you need to read which line number the error comes from, and then see *what's `nil`, and why is it `nil`?*